# Given the first 6 terms of a Fourier series expansion, is there a cusp form of weight 50 whose Fourier expansion begins that way

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

Is there a cusp form of weight 50 whose Fourier expansion begins with..
the first 6 terms being $q + 13q^2 + 611q^3 − 6546q^4 + 17727398783055q^5 + 5003897687242243q^6$. My guess is that I am supposed to use the fact that the coefficients of cusp form of weight 2k satisfy $a_n = O(n^k)$, but I am unsure how to actually use this.

Comment: You mean $\in S_{50}(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$. $O(n^k)$ is an asymptotic bound. The dimension is $\lfloor 50/12 \rfloor-1=3$ so you need to find a basis. Using [magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) : `M := ModularForms(Gamma1(1),50); M;
B := Basis(CuspidalSubspace(M)); B;`

Comment: If you meant of any level then it suffices to look at linear combination of $f(q^n)$ for various $n$

Comment: @reuns, I am unsure of how to use a basis: here's what I tried: the 3 basis elements are $q - 161408*q^4 ...,    q^2 - 4752*q^4 - 40099840*q^5 ...,
    q^3 - 96*q^4 - 192420*q^5 ...$ since I want 13 to be the coefficient of $q^2$ and 611 that of $q^3$, I multiplied the basis elements by these numbers to see I would obtain 6546 for $q^4,$ but I do not, hence there is no such cusp form.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Since you have $6$ coefficients to fit with a dim $3$ vector space, It is very possible there is no such modular form $\in S_{50}(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$. If you meant of any level, then $\in S_{50}(\Gamma_0(2))$ should work